# Enterprise Wiki: how to customize SitePages

Tags: 2010, page-layout, wiki

I've created a Wiki Page Library and I've noticed that when creating a new page, it doesn't have rating/categories/edit/history facilities as in the Pages library created by the publishing feature (Sharepoint Publishing Feature).

Questions:

- Why the Wiki Library does not have page layout with rating and categories and so on?
- Can I change the template used for this library? How to?

---

Edit

**I'd like to be able to perform something like that described in the this article http://blog.henryong.com/2010/06/08/how-to-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-page-layouts-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/
How to do that for a wiki page library?**

---

Please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Ratings and Categories is part of the Enterprise Wiki Site, not part of the regular Wiki Library.  The Ent Wiki Site, also has some flexibility with the PageLayouts.

I generally find that it is a good idea to store wiki content within a site or sub-site anyway so that it is somewhat more contained and maintainable.

Comment: Thanks. To be more precise, ratings & categories in the page layout are provided by Enterprise Wiki Site template, ONLY in the Pages system document library. By default other wiki libraries can not take advantage of this template, nor change their default one. That's my problem.